# most concise way to pass props to a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

here is my react hooks code.

```js
function onClick(){
  alert('clicked')
}
var className='clicker'
function Clicker1(){
  return <div {...{onClick,className}}>clicker 1</div>
}
function Clicker2(){
  var props={onClick,className}
  return <div {...props}>clicker 2</div>
}
function Clicker3(){
  return <div className={className} onClick={onClick}>clicker 3</div>
}
function Clickers(){
  return <><Clicker1/><Clicker2/><Clicker3/></>
}
ReactDOM.render(<Clickers/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

It demonstrates three different styles of passing props to a component. They all work just fine. My favorite style is clicker 1.

my question is: is there a more concise way to pass the props?

edit: this question is not option-based, its about concise representation, which can be accurately measured in number of characters, no option needed

Comment: Stop worrying about how many characters it takes and worry more about how understandable your code is to future developers.

Comment: It doesn't matter. EDIT: But TBH, I've seen clicker1 used in practice, and I personally hate it, it makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: i recommend option 3 just for readability, that's how it's done in the react official tutorial https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html, there might be cases where you want to overwrite the name of the prop you are passing to the child component.

Comment: @Adam . it hearts my eyes as well  hence the question

Comment: @yigal??  Your question states it's your favourite style. I said it's my *least* favourite. This question should really be closed, though.

Comment: @Adam I dislike the others ever more..

Comment: @yigal Go with your favorite if you are the only developer. If you have a team go with Clicker3. It will be much more readable for the majority.

Answer (score 2):

it appears that there is something in the works, but not merged yet
https://github.com/facebook/jsx/pull/121

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are following the correct path.

When there are multiple developers working on a single project, sometimes it becomes very confusing which and all props are getting passed and used in the component. It can lead to the breaking of the application or lack of info on the website.

with the first approach, you can actually see which props are getting passed and used.

```js
<Button
  fluid
  className={BEM_name}
  category={category}
  asButton={asButton}
  outline={outline}
  asLink={asLink}
  asAnchor={asAnchor}
  href={href}
  clickHandler={clickHandler}
  dataAutoId={dataAutoId}
>
```